# Problem icon WPF XAML - icons are not displayed

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a problem with icons.
In the edit mode, they are displayed and you cannot see them after starting the program.
I put in a different colored icon and it actually worked.
I don't know why this is happening with white icons.
I've been working on it for several hours and I don't know, will anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDJ9Q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SJ6Q.png)

```
<Window x:Class="Projekt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Projekt"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Kadry i płace Sputnik 2021" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="11*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DockPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="20">
            <Menu.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush>#457b9d</SolidColorBrush>
            </Menu.Background>
            <MenuItem Header="_Opcje" Foreground="#f1faee">
                <MenuItem Header="Kadry" Foreground="Black"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Płace" Foreground="Black"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Właściciele" Foreground="Black"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Przelew do ZUS"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Przypomnij"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Inne" Foreground="#f1faee">
                <MenuItem Header="Przelogowanie"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Ustawienie"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Kalkulator"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Wygląd"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Pobranie Podręcznika"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Pomoc" Foreground="#f1faee">
                <MenuItem Header="Pomoc na temat"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Co nowego"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Kalkulator"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="Powiadomienia"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="O programie"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock ="Left" Width="130" Background="#457b9d">
            <Grid Height="1" Background="White"></Grid>
            <Grid Height="19"></Grid>
            <ListView BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#457b9d">
                <ListViewItem Height="30">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Source/Icons/List_View_place.png"/>
                        <TextBlock  Text="Kadry" Margin="15 0 0 0" FontFamily="Candara" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem Height="30">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Source/Icons/List_View_Kadry.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Płace" Margin="15 0 0 0" FontFamily="Candara" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem Height="30">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Source/Icons/List_View_wlasciciele.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Właściciele" Margin="15 0 0 0" FontFamily="Candara" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem Height="30">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Source/Icons/List_View_zus.png"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Przedlew ZUS" Margin="15 0 0 0" FontFamily="Candara" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
            <Grid Height="140"></Grid>
            <ListView BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#457b9d">
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Source/Icons/List_View_użytkownik.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Firma" Margin="15 0 0 0" FontFamily="Candara" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>    
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Source/Icons/List_View_administrator.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Administrator" Margin="15 0 0 0" FontFamily="Candara" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="/Source/Icons/List_View_kalendarz.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="Kalendarz" Margin="15 0 0 0" FontFamily="Candara" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
            <Grid Height="1" Background="white"></Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 5 0 0">
                <ListView BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#457b9d">
                    <ListViewItem Margin="0 0 10 0">
                        <Image Source="/Source/Icons/List_View_ustawienia.png" Height="25" />
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
                <ListView BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="#457b9d">
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <Image Source="/Source/Icons/List_View_wyjscie.png" Height="25" />

                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the properties panel of your image in VisualStudio, you need to change the `Build Action` property to `Resource`.

[Example image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W21HC.png)